Selenium Module Not Working in PowerShell Universal Docker Linux Image
I am running a Docker-based PowerShell Universal (PSU) environment on a Linux image and trying to automate tasks using the Selenium module. Despite successfully installing the module, I am facing several issues when creating Selenium objects such as ChromeOptions or starting browsers like Chrome and Firefox.
Environment Details:

OS: Linux (Docker container)
PowerShell Version: 7.3.9
Selenium Module Version: 3.0.1 (Installed from PSGallery)

What I Did:

Installed Selenium Module:
Install-Module -Name Selenium -Force
Import-Module Selenium
Get-InstalledModule -Name Selenium

Result: Successfully installed and imported the module.

Verified WebDriver Binaries:
which chromedriver
which google-chrome
which firefox
which geckodriver

Result: All binaries are located in /usr/bin/ and are executable.

Set Up Xvfb (Headless Server):
Xvfb :99 -screen 0 1920x1080x24 &
export DISPLAY=:99

Error: Fatal server error: Server is already active for display 99.
Fix Attempt: Removed the lock file and retried:
rm -f /tmp/.X99-lock
Xvfb :99 -screen 0 1920x1080x24 &
export DISPLAY=:99

Result: Process started without errors after removing the lock file.

Attempted to Create Chrome Options in PowerShell:
$ChromeOptions = New-Object OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome.ChromeOptions
$ChromeOptions.AddArgument("--headless")
$ChromeOptions.AddArgument("--no-sandbox")
$ChromeOptions.AddArgument("--disable-dev-shm-usage")
$ChromeOptions.AddArgument("--disable-gpu")

Error: New-Object: Cannot find type [OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome.ChromeOptions]: verify that the assembly containing this type is loaded.

Attempted to Start Chrome in Headless Mode:
$Driver = Start-SeChrome -ChromeOptions $ChromeOptions

Error: Start-SeChrome: A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'ChromeOptions'.

Tried Manually Loading DLLs:
Add-Type -Path "/root/Selenium/Selenium/WebDriver.dll"
Add-Type -Path "/root/Selenium/Selenium/WebDriver.Support.dll"

Error: Add-Type: Cannot bind parameter 'Path' to the target. Exception setting 'Path': Cannot find path...

Checked Selenium Module Path:
$Module = Get-Module Selenium
$ModulePath = $Module.ModuleBase

Result: Selenium module path is correctly retrieved.

Tried Launching Firefox:
$FirefoxOptions = New-Object OpenQA.Selenium.Firefox.FirefoxOptions
$FirefoxOptions.BrowserExecutableLocation = "/usr/bin/firefox"
$Driver = Start-SeFirefox -FirefoxOptions $FirefoxOptions

Error: New-Object: Cannot find type [OpenQA.Selenium.Firefox.FirefoxOptions]: verify that the assembly containing this type is loaded.



Summary of Errors Encountered:

Cannot find type [OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome.ChromeOptions] in PowerShell.
Start-SeChrome: A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'ChromeOptions'.
Cannot find path '/root/Selenium/Selenium/WebDriver.dll' when manually loading DLLs.
Issues with running Xvfb due to an active display server lock.

Can someone help me fix this issue ?
